# Did he tell/ask you to say that?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

**Guy:** *If you ask me, Jack is the perfect man.*

**Woman Jack is dating:** *Did he tell/ask you to say that?*

Which of 'tell' and 'ask' would be more idiomatic here?

Comment: Both are idiomatic. They just mean slightly different things.

Comment: ‘Tell’ is more forceful, while ‘ask’ is more just a request.

Comment: Impossible to say. _Telling_ someone to do something is giving a command, _asking_ is more polite, so it depends on the woman's opinion of Jack's character!